# Modificar cadenas con memoria dinamica en C

Tags: array, c, punteros, array-bidimensional

En la función modificar no modifica bien los datos me muestra caracteres diferentes o se cierra antes de mostrar el contenido modificado, suele pasar cuando ingreso varios caracteres al modificar. ?Que es lo que ocurre? se asigno mal la memoria o no entiendo muy bien.

También al momento de pasar la función en el `main`:

```
modificar(array);
```

Parece que no guarda los datos y hace que el programa se cierre

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void mostrar(char **);
void modificar(char **);

int main(){

    int N = 2;
    int i,lon=3,tam;
    char **array;
    char cadena[10];//para el texto;
    
    array = (char**)malloc(lon*sizeof(char*)); 
    if(array == NULL){      
        printf("No se pudo asignar");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<lon;i++){
        
        printf("\nIngrese un nombre: ");
        scanf("%10[^\n]",cadena);
        fflush(stdin);
        tam = strlen(cadena);
        array[i] = (char*)malloc(tam*sizeof(char));
            
        strcpy(array[i],cadena);
                
    } 
  
    for(i=0;i<lon;i++){     
        printf("\n\nNOMBRE: %s\n ",array[i]);
    }

    modificar(array);
    for(i=0;i<lon;i++){
        printf("\n\nNOMBRE: %s\n ",array[i]);   
    }
    getch();
    
    free(array);
}

void modificar(char **array){   

    int i,mod,tam;
    char nuevo[10];

    printf("\n\nIngrese cual quiere modificar: ");
    scanf("%d",&mod);

    printf("\n\nIngrese el nuevo nombre: ");
    scanf("%s",nuevo);
    tam = strlen(nuevo);
    array[mod] = (char*)realloc(array,1+tam*sizeof(char));

    if(array[mod]==NULL){
        printf("\n\nFallo al asignar memoria");
        exit (-1);
    }

    for(i=0;i<strlen(nuevo)+1;i++){
        array[mod][i]=nuevo[i];
        if(strlen(nuevo)+1 == i) array[mod][i] == '\0';
    }       
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){   
        printf("\n\nModificado: %s",array[i]);  
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para copiar cadenas deberías usar `strcpy`. Reemplaza esto:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(nuevo)+1;i++){
    array[mod][i]=nuevo[i];
    if(strlen(nuevo)+1 == i) array[mod][i] == '\0';
}
```

Por esto:

```
strcpy(array[mod], nuevo);
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que la llamada a `realloc` no es correcta:

```
   array[mod] = (char*)realloc(array,1+tam*sizeof(char));
// ~~~~~~~~~~                  ~~~~~
// array[mod]                  array
```

Tras esta llamada, si la reserva se ha realizado correctamente, habrás invalidado `array`. La llamada correcta sería

```
char* temp = (char*)realloc(array[mod],1+tam*sizeof(char));
if (temp == NULL)
{
    // No se ha podido completar la reserva de memoria
}
array[mod] = temp;
```

De esta forma, además, verificas que la reserva de memoria no ha dado problemas

Comment: Funciono!!, no me habia fijado del error en la llamada de realloc. Tengo una pequeña duda con respecto al strcpy, cuando reservo la memoria con realloc se borra el contenido previo? para que strcpy pueda copiar todo sin problema

Comment: @Ilhr2n strcpy sobreescribe la memoria con el contenido nuevo, luego el contenido que hubiese en esa región de memoria se perderá. Si no quieres que eso pase necesitas habilitar una nueva región de memoria donde almacenar los datos